# Creating Matplotlib Toolbar in Python Traits Editor

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt4, toolbar, traits

I'm working on a QT4 Traits-GUI in Python using Matplotlib for image display, and so far I have [this](https://mail.enthought.com/pipermail/enthought-dev/2012-May/031065.html) editor modified in an attempt to include a toolbar.

```
from traitsui.qt4.editor import Editor
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar

class _MPLFigureEditor(Editor):
"""
Building custom figure editor for displaying matplotlib figures with a qt4-based Traits interface
"""
    scrollable  = True

    def init(self, parent):
        self.control = self._create_canvas(parent)
        self.set_tooltip()

    def update_editor(self):
        pass

    def _create_canvas(self, parent):
        mpl_canvas = FigureCanvas(self.value) #self.value is the figure linked to the editor factory
        mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(mpl_canvas,???)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(mpl_toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(mpl_canvas)
        return layout
```

Is this the correct place to create the toolbar? What would be second argument to NavigationToolbar in this case? I'm trying to follow the examples I've found on adding toolbars as QWidgets to figures, but these all create a main_frame within a QMainWindow-based class, not a Traits Editor. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Since `parent` is a `QGridLayout` itself, we can add the toolbar widget directly to the layout in row 2, column 1 (to place it below the canvas, which I believe is added as a widget in the view-editor creation).

```
from traitsui.qt4.editor import Editor
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar

class _MPLFigureEditor(Editor):
"""
Building custom figure editor for displaying matplotlib figures with a qt4-based Traits interface
"""
    scrollable  = True

    def init(self, parent):
        self.control = self._create_canvas(parent)
        mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.control,None)
        parent.addWidget(mpl_toolbar,2,1)
        self.set_tooltip()
        return

    def update_editor(self):
        pass

    def _create_canvas(self, parent):
    """ Create the MPL canvas. """
        mpl_canvas = FigureCanvas(self.value)
        return mpl_canvas
```

Image zoom/pan does seem to run a bit slow, but that could be another issue altogether.